# H-bridge porblem

Tags: h-bridge

This is my first experiment with MOSFET. I have built this design but the n-channel MOSFET getting hot. Is there mistakes I have made?

[image]

I have no problems wit p-channel it measured -12V VGS and 200mv VDS, but with n-channel I have measured VGS about 11V and VDS about 4V --- the problem here is that in Multisim simulation VDS should be around 200mV, so from where this 4V come?
I want to use this circuit with PWM.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Is it used with PWM or just a static thing?

Comment: Do both N-Channel FETs measure the same (when they are on)?

Comment: Yes, I will use it for PWM

Comment: P- channel measure: VGS= -12V , VDS= 200mV

Comment: N=Channel measure: VGS= 12V, VDS= 4V

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the circuit for low speed PWM or static control so maybe you bought the IRF530s from a dodgy place?

Comment: I have bought it from guaranteed seller. Is there any method to check it?

Comment: not an expert, but those 480 ohm resistors seems to much for me, just in my opinion they should be in range of 10-20 ohm, else you have long transient times

Comment: If you run it awhile in one direction, only one of the n-types should get hot. If you then run it in the other direction, does the other n-type get hot as well? It might be that you have a bad FET. If both n-types get hot, there is something very strange going on. And I agree that, for PWM use, you should cut your gate resistors by at least a factor of 10.

Comment: OK, I will reduce gate resistances. For n-channel, yes when I run it in one direction only one get hot, then when I run it in the other direction the other n-channel get hot.

Comment: The SOA graph shows operation of the IRF530 at 2.4A is limited by Rds(on). From that graph, operation at around 2A lines up with 4V Vds.

Comment: I still a beginner. Could you explain more!

Comment: Excellent discussion of SOA graphs at https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2015/05/02/understanding-mosfet-data-sheets-part-2-safe-operating-area-soa-graph

Comment: I misread the graph (shows it can happen to anyone) - 2A lines up with about 0.4V

Comment: Thank you, I have learned something new. So, what might be the problem?

Comment: When the n-type gate is at 12 volts, what is the gate voltage at the p-type above it? If the p-type is not getting turned off adequately you'll get shoot-thru current and heat both FETs. And what 12-volt supply are you using? What current limit, and can you monitor the output current?